# implement custom workflow in azure functions with time trigger in dynamics 365 at specified time

Tags: c#, azure-functions, workflow, microsoft-dynamics

I have a custom workflow that copies the attachments from an email and places the copy in the notes.At the moment, this process is ran manually.
I want to enable this process to be ran automatically everyday at a specified time of day.
However i am unsure how to do this.

```
public class Email_Attachments_to_Regarding_Document_Store : CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
    {
        ITracingService tracer = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
        IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        try
        {
            //Retrieve Email the workflow is running against from Dynamics
            Email email = service.Retrieve(context.PrimaryEntityName, context.PrimaryEntityId, new ColumnSet(true)).ToEntity<Email>();

            //Retrieve the attachment mimes related to the email
            DataCollection<Entity> mimes = service.RetrieveMultiple(new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = ActivityMimeAttachment.EntityLogicalName,
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
                Criteria =
                {
                    Conditions =
                    {
                        //Filter by related Email, 'objectid' is the related email.
                        new ConditionExpression("objectid", ConditionOperator.Equal, email.Id)
                    }
                }
            }).Entities;

            foreach(ActivityMimeAttachment mime in mimes)
            {
                Annotation note = new Annotation
                {
                    AnnotationId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    DocumentBody = mime.Body,
                    IsDocument = true,
                    FileName = mime.FileName,
                    MimeType = mime.MimeType,
                    ObjectTypeCode = email.RegardingObjectId.LogicalName,
                    ObjectId = email.RegardingObjectId
                };
                note.IsDocument = true;
                service.Create(note);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

This code copies the email attachments into notes. However i am unable to run this code at a specified time of day. 
The code below is an azure function that connects to dynamics

```
 public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");


        IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService> orgServiceManagement = 
            ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IOrganizationService>(new Uri("https://disco.crm11.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc"));


        AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials = new AuthenticationCredentials();
        authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxx@s.co.uk";
        authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxxxx";
        AuthenticationCredentials tokenCredentials = orgServiceManagement.Authenticate(authCredentials);

        //Retreive the service

        IOrganizationService service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgServiceManagement, tokenCredentials.SecurityTokenResponse);



    }
}
```

i want the azure function to implement/run the custom workflow but i am not sure how

Comment: have you tried with windows task scheduler?

Comment: This will not work as it needs to be ran on all computers in an organization. the needs to be hosted in dynamics

Comment: What's your main code? And which webjob sdk you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this isnt too late. When I've needed to do something similar, I create an Action in Dynamics. The action will call the Workflow Activity.

I then call the action from my Azure Function App Code like this.

```cs
 OrganizationRequest req = new OrganizationRequest([insert action name here]);

 //execute the request
 OrganizationResponse response = organizationService.Execute(req);
```

Also I'd avoid putting credentials in your Azure Code. Ideally use Azure Key Vault for this. You can refer this post for ways to do this. [Azure Function Authentication To Dynamics CRM Using Azure Key Vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715901/authenticate-azure-function-app-to-connect-to-dynamics-365-crm-online/51046222#51046222)